# Counter for each row in a case

Tags: php, prestashop, counter

I programmed this code but I have a problem that in every row show the same value "1". I would a counter for positioning or number for the row

```
Position
1
2
3
4
```

Here the code: what I need to change or what I doing wrong?

```
case "18": 
                     $html.='<td class="product_tax_name product_list_content product_list_content_'.($j+1)
                .' product_list_col_'.($j+1).'">';

                for($i=1; $i<=1; $i=$i+1)
                        {
                   $html.= $i;
                   $i++;
                    }
                $html.='</td>';

                break; 


        }
        return $html;
```

Comment: What is $j? Is it not being set or is it outside of the code you are displaying?

Comment: Please provide full code and describe clearly...
Your question isn't clear...

Comment: $j is only for numbering the column. like product_list_col_3'". What i want is, that in that column the code generate a counter foreach row, starting with 1 and next row is 2 next is 3

Comment: please check this:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I4fsM5gj9kY1gfg0ZZ3onzQPFl-ywqbw

Comment: you can see the first column is only 1,1,1,1 i would 1,2,3,4,5,6,....

Comment: so `$j=0` then?  try `++$j`

Comment: So it looks like the loop only runs while i is less than or equal to 1. So once i is greater than 1 the loop stops.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment `$j` with `++$j`

```
 ++$j;

 $html.='<td class="product_tax_name product_list_content product_list_content_'.$j.' product_list_col_'.$j.'">';
```

For example purposes

```
$j = 0;

foreach(range(1,5) as $blah){
   echo (++$j)."\n"; //you can ignore the line return "\n"
}
```

See the example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dbf1f2d6d471f8a423f62ad065b3b906d627d55a)

Outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

-Note- in order to increment without warning messages you have to first define So like I did in the above example.

Another way to do this is:

```
$j += 1;
```

Which is the same as saying

```
$j = $j+1;
```

The Crux of your issue is that you are not assigning anything, your just takeing the value of `$j` adding `1` and outputting it without changing the value of `$j`.  What I showed above are ways to do both the assignment and the modification of the variable.

So if `$j` was equal to `4` you would get `5` every time.  You either set it to `0` or did not define it.

**Also** we have this mess to contend with

```
for($i=1; $i<=1; $i=$i+1){
  $html.= $i;
  $i++;
}
```

This loops one time, and you wind up with `$i=3`.  Also it's bad form.

```
for($i=1; $i<=1; ++$i){
  $html.= $i;
}
//outputs 1
```

Now it loops still `1` time but you end with `$i=2`

**UPDATE**

If the above for loop is what you mean when you say

> $html.= "put here the counter(1,2,3,4,5)"

Then well yea you're only looping 1 time so you will get only one number. Try this,

```
for($i=1; $i<=10; ++$i){
  $html.= $i;
}
//outputs 12345678910 as there is no separator here.
```

Or even better

```
$html .= implode(",", range(1,10));
 //Outputs: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10
```

So to put it all together ( literally )

```
  $html.= "put here the counter(".implode(",", range(1,4)).")";
```

As for what the "range" is on this, what it counts. Well tell me what this means and I will let you know:

> I would a counter for positioning or number for the row
>
> Position 1 2 3 4

Comment: Hi, i mean i need one value for each row, not 5 values in the row.ss

Comment: Like Row 1 value 1, row 2 value 2, row 3 value 3